# EF does not give complete json when it has one entity that has one navigation property like itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a project in asp.net core and in this project, I have two entity. First entity is product

```
public class Product
{
   public int id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual Brand Brand { get; set; }
}
```

My second class is

```
public class Brand
{
  public Brand()
  {
     Products = new List<Products>();
  }
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public virtual List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and I have an APIController like this

```
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
   public object GetProducts()
   {
     return decorDB.Products              
      .Include(p => p.Brand);
   }
 }
```

thing I get is a json like this

```
[
  {
     "id":1,
     "name":"iPhone",
     "brand":
        {
          "id":1,
          "name":"Apple",
          "products":[
```

as you see it's not complete, I think EF breaks it to prevent a loop.
I want something like this

```
[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"iPhone",
         "brand":
            {
              "id":1,
              "name":"Apple",
              "products":[]
            }
       }
]
```

I don't have any idea to do what!

Comment: How are you converting to json?

Comment: you haven't set a foreign key of `Brand` id to `Product` entity just like => `public int BrandId { get; set; }`

Comment: @Stefan I added a API Controller. - Empty.

Comment: @er-mfahhgk I add it but nothing changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: not tested but to long for a comment.*

I would suggest to make the following changes:

First try to change your action result signature:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
```

Next: try to explicitly disable the round trip in your startup:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
   {
       options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
   });
```

Comment: I only added the second part and It works like a Mercedes Benz. Thank you.

Comment: Glad it helped. Nevertheless; making your return type a `IEnumerable<Product>`, makes sure you cannot mistakenly return an unexpected type. It makes it strong typed.